# Animate incremented number and show decimal value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple counter in jQuery that starts from zero and increments by `5.5` but it only shows the value `5` without the decimal point.

I tried tweaking the regular expression but that didn't work.

I also need to add some sort of animation to the number instead of having it jump from 0 to 5 to 10... I would like it to ease and count up as it increments.

The HTML

```
<div class="label label-success count">0</div>
```

The Javascript

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(5.5);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.count').html(function(i, val) {
            val = val.replace(/,/g,'');
            return (parseFloat(val,10)+randomIntFromInterval(2,30000)).toString().replace(/\B(?=(^-?(?!.{12})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$))/g, ",");
        })
    }, 1000);

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/62vcz9qs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are only getting 5 and not the 5.5 is because you are specifically calling `Math.floor(5.5)` which returns `5` not `5.5` if you remove `Math.floor` your counter will go up by 5.5.

Here are the docs for Math.floor : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Answer (score 1):

I made some pretty basic changes and removed the function `randomIntFromInterval()`, as it seems pretty unnecessary. I simply made the interval time (1000/5.5) and made the increment just 1 second.

This achieves the "easing up" animation you wanted, and increments by 5.5 every second.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    $('.count').html(function(i, val) {
        val = val.replace(/,/g,'');
        return (parseFloat(val,10)+1).toString().replace(/\B(?=(^-?(?!.{12})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$))/g, ",");
    })
}, (1000/5.5));
```

});

Check out the JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/62vcz9qs/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.count').html(function(i, val) {
                val = val.replace(/,/g,'');
                return val = parseFloat(val)+5.5
            })
        }, 1000);

    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhruv1992/62vcz9qs/8/

Comment: well the code is shortest and works, doesnt it works??

Comment: As noted above, no. It's preforming concatenation, not addition.

Comment: yes sorry, got it, some one edited my fiddle. I have updated my answer